# Maven cannot handle Unicode character

Tags: java, maven, unicode

I run code by java, Unicode character can be showed correct but when i run code by maven (Mvn clean test) Unicode character show incorrect. I have user extent report and extend report show log with incorrect Unicode character, too

```
<groupId>groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>api</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                 <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>.\testsuites\run1.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.9</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180130</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.samczsun</groupId>
        <artifactId>skype4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.ashot</groupId>
        <artifactId>ashot</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.gpedro.integrations.slack</groupId>
        <artifactId>slack-webhook</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-sheets</artifactId>
        <version>v4-rev525-1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-drive</artifactId>
        <version>v3-rev124-1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.javacrumbs.json-unit</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-unit</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

```
@Test(enabled = true)
public void Demo_001() throws IOException {

    String text = "Đây là văn bản tiếng việt";
    System.out.println(text);

            //extent report log
    BaseObject.addReportLog(LogType.INFO, text);

}
```

Actual result : 
?y l v?n b?n ti?ng vi?t

Expected result : 
Đây là văn bản tiếng việt

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: There are many possible causes, maven being not the most probable one: is your Java source code really encoded in UTF-8? On which operating system are you running your code? What codepage/encoding/font does the displaying console use?

Comment: I resolved my issus by add argLine : <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
To POM.xml on plugin maven-surefire-plugin

Comment: @Raw2008 you can write it as answer and accept it

Comment: @barbsan tks your guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue by add DFile encoding UTF-8 on sureFire Plugin at POM.xml

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>.\testsuites\run1.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since version `3.0.0-M1`, both [surefire](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#encoding) and [failsafe](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#encoding) plugins have the `encoding` parameter. You can configure it like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```